# How to format output when vals are lists?

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary, formatting

In the example, below, I'd like to:

- add a blank line after each new key to make the output easier to read
- put keys in alphabetical order (So the keys are alphabetized, and then the values are alphabetized for each key)

What is the most pythonic way to do this?

*Super basic example:*

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}

for clothes, colors in wardrobe.items():
    for color in sorted(colors):
        print("{} {}".format(color, clothes))
```

Output:

```
blue shirt
red shirt
white shirt
black jeans
blue jeans
```

Comment: Does your code works?

Comment: As it is, it works And it sorts the values. It does not sort the keys first (or at all, really).
It doesn't leave a line break after the last instance of each key.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `f-strings` -

```
wardrobe = {"shirt":["red","blue","white"], "jeans":["blue","black"]}

for clothes in wardrobe: # .items is not unpythonic, but I do not like to use it

    for color in sorted(wardrobe[clothes]): # This may seem long, but it keeps track of things

        print(f'{color} {clothes}') # Use f-string
```

You can use `.items` but I didn't it. So, if it feels ok for you, you can use `.items`.

Or a list comprehension (I do not recommend this since we are not "building" a list here anyway) -

```
print(*[f'{color} {clothes}' for clothes in wardrobe for color in sorted(wardrobe[clothes])],sep='\n')
```

Comment: F-string - yes.
But your code doesn't alphabetize by key, then value and doesn't add a blank line between the two keys.

Comment: I do not understand _alphabetize_ by key. Can you explain? Perhaps you want to sort it based on the keys, I think

Comment: Yes, that's it - the output would be alphabetized first by key, then by each value associated with each key.   _____ jeans should come before _______ shirt.

I was able to sort the values, but not the keys.